# CSS Animation does not work on Mac chrome but works fine for iPad Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a very simple animation that works fine on safari and google chrome on iPad, but not on the google chrome on my Mac. I'm new to CSS and I'm not sure why this happens. If you can give me some insights that would be great! 
This is my HTML part:

```
<div class="truck">
<img class="truck" src="deliver200x159.png" width="100px" height="80px"/>
<p id="deliver">We Do Delivery!</p>
```

And this is my CSS part:

```
div.truck {
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
color: #FE93D7;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
background-color: none;
-webkit-animation: running 10s infinite linear; 
     -o-animation: running 10s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: running 10s infinite linear;
   -moz-animation: running 10s infinite linear;
animation-animation: running 10s infinite linear;
}

div.truck:hover{
 -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
 -o-animation-play-state: paused;
 -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
 -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
 animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes running {
  0%   {left: 0%;}
  100%  {left: 100%;}
}

@-o-keyframes running {
  0%   {left: 0%;}
  100%  {left: 100%;}
}

@-ms-keyframes running {
  0%   {left: 0%;}
  100%  {left: 100%;}
}

@-moz-keyframes running {
  0%   {left: 0%;}
  100%  {left: 100%;}
}

@keyframes running {
  0%   {left: 0%;}
  100%  {left: 100%;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that your Mac chrome version has dropped the `-webkit-` prefix, and it looks like your standard animation declaration is a little off.

This:

```
animation-animation: running 10s infinite linear;
```

Should be:

```
animation: running 10s infinite linear;
```

**Edit**

After playing with it more, it appears that chrome doesn't like the `running` animation name. Changing it to something less generic seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that mistake out. I fixed it but the animation still doesn't work for Mac Chrome. Could you think of any other reason why?

Comment: @JessicaHur after playing with it, it looks like chrome doesn't like the `running` name for the animation. Try changing it to something like `runninganim`. I'll update my answer as soon as possible.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I fixed the animation name to runningTruck and it worked! Thank you!